# Horizontal and vertical histogram of an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, logic, histogram

I need to get the horizontal and vertical histogram a given array. Following is the C - code that I tried. Is there any way to improve this or any easy alternate method?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define size 10
int main() {
  int array[size] = {2, 5, 7, 8, 10, 16, 7, 4, 3, 4};
  int i, j, bigCount, temp;

 /* To get Horizontal Histogram */
  for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    printf("\n%3d|", i);
    for (j = 0; j < array[i]; ++j)
      printf(" #");
  }

  /* To find the biggest count */
  bigCount = array[0];
  for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    if(array[i] > bigCount)
      bigCount = array[i];
  temp = bigCount;
  printf("\n\n");

  /* To get Vertical Histogram */
  for (i = 0; i < bigCount; ++i) {
    printf("\n%3d|", bigCount - i);
     for (j = 0; j < size; ++j)
       if (array[j] < temp)
     printf("   ");
       else {
     printf("  #");
     --array[j];
       }
     --temp;
  }

 /* printing the x-axis */
  printf("\n    ");
  for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) 
    printf("  -", i);
  printf("\n    ");
  for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) 
    printf("%3d", i);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
```

}

Comment: "easy" in the sense that using less number of variables, loops, functions etc.. Using reduced lines of code altogether..

Answer (score 1):

Nicely done.  However, there are some little things which may be improved:

It seems that you have missed the x-axis on the horizontal histogram.

Also, on the line:

```
bigcount = array[1];
```

there is an off-by-one error.

The next step I would take would be to add some features to allow a user to input arbitrary data.

Comment: I could give `bigCount = array[0]`. But it doesn't actually make any difference either.

Comment: True, but that's only because array[0] is not the maximum value.  If and when it is, your histogram will be incorrect.

Comment: I don't understand your point.. however at the end of the loop for finding the bigCount, we ll get the  biggest value irrespective of the initial value of `bigCount` as long as it is a value inside that array.

Comment: You are correct.  However, if there is only 1 element in array, then your program will fail.  By using array[0], you account for an edge case that would have caused a segfault otherwise.